# MySQL Server Localhost vs IP Address

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

We have recently upgraded our server at work, and are currently in the process of manually migrating all our data over, including a MySQL Database. I am currently trying to connect to the new database on IP xxx.xxx.xxx.2 which is what I have allocated the server. But, it will not allow me to connect using the root access credentials I set it up with, from the server directly, or my Macbook using Workbench. If I try to connect via 127.0.0.1 (Localhost) it allows me to connect with the same credentials direct from the server.

This made me think, does the server connect to 127.0.0.1 in the same way it would connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.2? Obviously, the .2 address will go across the network, where as localhost I would assume connects directly? If it does connect in the same way, what would be stopping me connecting?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at the output from `SELECT user, host, password FROM mysql.users`

Comment: Figured it, the service was in a pending-start state, restarted and working now :) Thank you though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noticed that the MySQL service icon in my server task tray was yellow, upon hovering over it turned out the service was in a "pending-start" state. Restarted the service and can now connect.